# For Each Loaded Line (From a File with Mixed Strings and Integers), Create a Person Type Object

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that reads data (of type `string` and `int`) from a file. Then, it creates an object named `Person` and puts it into an `ArrayList`.
For this task I am using the `Scanner`.

With methods like `next()`, `nextLine()`,  I'm able to read/parse the data and create `Person`; however, I don't really know how to handle the situation when the input will have mixed `persons`.

My task says that there could be 2 options (input can include):

1. name, yearOfBirth
2. or, name,yearOfBirth,carName and Color (r,g,b)

Option 1: With `next()`, `nextLine()`, I know (more or less) how to do it:

```
John 1980 Mercedes 255 255 102
```

- In the `ArrayList`, John should look like `[John 1980 Mercedes 255 255 102]`
  but I do not know what to do when input will be for ex.:

Option 2:

```
John 1980 Mercedes 255 255 102
Mary 1997
Alice 1993 Skoda 0 127 153
```

- In this situation, the program should recognize that the Mary do not have a car and in the `ArrayList`. Mary will look like `[Mary 1997 null]`

So, class `Person` has 2 constructors:

```
public Person(String name, int yearOfBirth, Car car)
```

and

```
public Person(String name, int yearOfBirth)
```

and `Overrided toString()` method.

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner sc;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);

            while (sc.hasNext()) {

 // here, i think, i should create an Person and add 'him/her' to ArrayList<Person>
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("End of Program.");
    }

}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    int yearOfBirth;
    Car car;

    public Person(String name, int yearOfBirth, Car car) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.car = car;
    }

    public Person(String name, int yearOfBirth) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return name + " " + yearOfBirth + " " + car;
    }
```

Car class:

```
public class Car {
    String nameCar;
    Color color;
    int r, g, b;

    public Car(String nameCar, int r, int g, int b) {
        this.nameCar = nameCar;
        this.color = new Color(r, g, b);
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return nameCar + " " + r + " " + g + " " + b;
    }
}
```

Input should include`ArrayList` of `Persons`

Comment: When using `nextLine`, you can split the String you retrieve, then check the length of the array you retrieve from `String::split` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this example you can read the whole line with your scanner, using `sc.nextLine()` (also use `sc.hasNextLine()` on the while loop). Then you can get the fields on a string array like this:

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
String[] fields = line.split(" ");
//separate all the "words" in the string by a space character
```

After doing this you can test if the length of the `fields` array is 6 =, meaning that the person has a car or only 2.